# Can / Should ScriptableObjects be used to store character data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a turn based RPG and wanted to know whether its a good idea to use `ScriptableObjects` as a way to store character data that will change at one point or another at runtime like stats, inventory items, spells & abilities, etc. I know that `ScriptableObjects` are usually predefined and are used as read-only, so I wanted to ask around before I committed to it.

Comment: If your data is going to change, a normal code sounds like a better solution to me (for instance: `InventoryController`), as scriptable objects are more frequently used to create assets with data that won't change at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScriptableObjects` Are great for storing data at runtime, but if you want data to persist between sessions of your game, you're going to want to write the data to a file.

[Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) can be used to get a path to a place where you can save game data in files. You can then create a file and [save your data in json format](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html).

This would allow you to modify your scriptable objects at runtime, then when it comes to saving the game, convert them to json text and store your data in a text file.

Then when you open your game up again you can read this file and re-apply the data to your scriptable objects.

Just make sure all of your data is serialisable and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ScriptableObjects are a great way to store character data.
I would actually suggest a much easier way depending on the complexity of your game. Unity has something called Visual Scripting which exposes 3 core and very interesting types of Variables.

1. Scene Variables - Exist only in Scene
2. Application Variables - Exists during the lifetime of an application
3. Saved Variables - Exists even after an application is closed

This can be accessed via code as well as through node-like graphs.

using Unity.VisualScripting

Check it out here: https://unity.com/features/unity-visual-scripting